# Slicing string from start

Tags: python, string, slice

In Python:

```
s = "Gwen Stefani"
a = s[:0]
b = s[0]

print type(a) # str
print type(b) # str
print len(a)  # 0
print len(b)  # 1
```

I understand that `s[:0]` is empty, but it also means from the start of the string so I would have thought that:

```
s[:0] is the same as s[0]
```

Comment: [:0] mean you take 0 character from the beginning.
[0] means you take the first character.

Comment: Because `a = ""` and `b = "G"`, that;s why the type of both is `str` but the `len()` is `0`, `1` resp.

Comment: `s[0:0] ==s[:0] means from 0 to 0`

Comment: `s[:0]` is the substring starting at the start of the string to the char of position 0 (not included) so it's the empty string, `s[0]` is the character at position 0 so it's "G"

Answer (score 1):

You can read about the behaviour of string slicing at https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings, which includes an illustration of how to interpret indices.

In particular, it states:

> One way to remember how slices work is to think of the indices as pointing between characters, with the left edge of the first character
>   numbered 0. Then the right edge of the last character of a string of n
>   characters has index n, for example:
>
> ```
>  +---+---+---+---+---+---+
>  | P | y | t | h | o | n |
>  +---+---+---+---+---+---+
>  0   1   2   3   4   5   6
> -6  -5  -4  -3  -2  -1
> ```
>
> The first row of numbers gives the position of the indices 0...6 in the string; the second row gives the corresponding negative
>   indices. **The slice from i to j consists of all characters between the
>   edges labeled i and j, respectively.**

(*Emphasis mine*)

When `i` and `j` are both `0` (and `i` defaults to `0` if not specified), there are no characters between them, so the resulting substring is the empty string, `""`, which has type `str` and length `0`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand what slicing does:

```
x = s[:n]
```

now, x contains values of s[0],s[1],...,s[n-1], `but not s[n]`

So, s[:0] returns values from index 0 ,to index before 0, which is nothing.

Answer (score 0):

The last index you take is the one before the specified number, that is:
a[x:y] means from x to y-1:

```
In [4]: s[0:3]
Out[4]: 'Gwe'
```

So you are not taking from zero to zero, you are taking from zero to minus one, which is empty